# Handling Incomplete write() Calls

Tags: c, linux, unix, io

In Linux/Unix, the write() call may end up writing fewer bytes than requested:

> The number of bytes written may be less than  count  if,  for  example,
>   there  is  insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the
>   RLIMIT_FSIZE resource limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)),  or  the
>   call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than
>   count bytes.  (See also pipe(7).)

The C standard library's fwrite() has the same behaviour.  Most code I've seen ignores this possibility, choosing to handle errors in the following manner:

```
int ret = write(fd, buf, size);
if (ret < 0) {
    printf("Couldn't write %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

I've personally gotten in the habit of modifying the condition so that we are checking

```
if (ret != size) {
    printf("Couldn't write %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Which notices this condition.  However, I've also noticed that my program occasionally exits with:

```
Couldn't write /some/file: Success
```

I suppose this isn't too surprising.  But then what is the standard, robust, clean way to handle this case?  Clearly "silent data corruption"---which seems to be the behaviour of every tutorial ever---isn't OK.  I could modify my code so that it specially detects this case and exits.

But the example provided in man 2 write is just an example.  Are there other examples where retrying would be the way to go (EINTR is an example...)?  How do I detect these, and more importantly, make sure I've handled every case?  Isn't there a standard clean way to make these error handlers?

Comment: Write can either *suceed* in write *some* or all data, in which case it returns the amount of data written without setting `errno`, or it can *fail* without writing *any data*, in which case it always returns `-1` and sets `errno`.  For example, if `write()` is interrupted by a signal after writing *some* data, it does not set `errno` to `EINTR`, this only happens if `write()` is interrupted before it can write any data at all. Consequently, `write()` will never return `0` when called with a positive `size` argument.

Comment: I see, I'm starting to get it.  Playing around with this, I notice that if, after my write() succeeds in writing *some* data, I immediately repeat the operation, *then* it will fail to write more data, returning "No space left on device".  I was scared that I would get into an endless "can't write more data but also no error" loop.

Comment: If no data is being written, then `write()` will return an error, unless you passed 0 for `size`, in which case it can return 0 if no error condition is present. `write()` cannot return 0 for a nonzero length argument as far as I know.

Comment: assuming both 'ret' and 'size' are integers (not size_t) then this line: `if (ret != size) {` is not correct for all cases.   suggest: `if (ret < size) { // handle error }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write will return a negative number if nothing is written under two circumstances:

- A temporary error (e.g. `EINTR`, `EAGAIN`, and `EWOULDBLOCK`); the first of these can happen with any write, the second two (broadly) only on non-blocking I/O.
- A permanent error.

Normally you would want to retry the first, so the routine is to repeat the write if `EINTR`, `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` is returned (though I've seen argument against the latter).

For example:

```
ssize_t
write_with_retry (int fd, const void* buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret;
    do
    {
         ret = write(fd, buf, size);
    } while ((ret<0) && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK));
    return ret;
}
```

Also note (from the man page) that write can return a number of bytes written less than you requested in the case of non-blocking I/O, or blocking I/O (as the linux man-page makes clear).

OS-X man-page extract:

> When using non-blocking I/O on objects, such as sockets, that are subject to flow control, `write()` and `writev()` may write fewer bytes than requested; the return value must be noted, and the remainder of the operation should be retried when possible.

Linux man-page extract (my emphasis):

> The number of bytes written may be less than count if, for example, there is  insufficient  space  on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource limit is encountered (see `setrlimit(2)`), *or the call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes*.

You would normally be handling those with `select()`, but to handle that case manually:

```
ssize_t
write_with_retry (int fd, const void* buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret;
    while (size > 0) {
        do
        {
             ret = write(fd, buf, size);
        } while ((ret < 0) && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK));
        if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
        size -= ret;
        buf += ret;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The note at the very end is the one relevant to my case.  I'm not using sockets or interrupts or nonblocking mode.  But the information provided is all useful and interesting and well written.  Thank you!

Comment: Note it may be difficult to avoid using signals (that's what cause EINTR). For instance someone may press `^Z`.

Comment: You mean `^C`?  I don't setup a custom signal handler for `^C`, so a partial write is expected behaviour.

If you really mean `^Z`, that would be bad.  I thought `^Z` sent `SIGTSTP`.  Can we really get EINTR from that?

Comment: @JeffTaylor any signal handler you have installed (`SIGWINCH` or whatever) in order to run will interrupt any system call running at the time. That's how it gets back to user space. Not coding for `EINTR` sounds pretty suicidal to me.

Answer (score 3):

The `(ret < 0)` condition ignores short writes and only reports formal errors.  This is arguably sloppy, but fixing it requires extra code — it is plausible to think that it would mean you should use a function wrapped around the `write` system call.

The `(ret != size)` condition is much more sensitive as a test, but the follow-up actions are complex enough that again, it needs to be a function wrapped around `write()`.

In a generic wrapper function, you need to distinguish:

- `ret > 0 && ret < size`: in this case, you should loop and try to write the residue of the buffer.  You could simply return the number of bytes actually written (cumulatively).
- `ret == 0`: you wrote zero bytes, but there wasn't an error.  <s>This could happen if you have the file descriptor open with `O_NONBLOCK`.  You should probably have a strategy for dealing with this — but it is going to be context dependent.  Is a sleep appropriate?  Or do you just retry — and risk hammering the system?  Do you just try a few times?</s>  You get 0 bytes written if you request 0 bytes to be written, but that would be covered under `ret == size`. Otherwise, it is not clear that `ret == 0` is possible. For a generic wrapper, if this occurs, maybe the best approach is to return the 0.
- `ret < 0`: the chances are high that any retry will fail.  Return the error condition.  However, it is worth retrying if you get one of a selected few errors: EINTR if the `write()` is interrupted by a signal; EAGAIN for a write on a non-blocking file descriptor that would block — sometimes known as EWOULDBLOCK; maybe a few others but none of the normal errors for [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) are plausible candidates.

Most serious Unix (or Linux) system programming books discuss this.  For example:

- W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
  [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)
- Marc J Rochkind
  [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543)

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted are very helpful, in particular FUZxxl's comment pointed out an important fact:

*`write()` will never succeed without writing data.*

For my own case, I'm running out of disk space, and I *really* wanted `write()` to give me `ENOSPC`.  The solution, then, is to retry incomplete `write()` calls.  The first call will return successfully.  The second call will be unable to write any data.  Since it can't write *anything*, it then returns `ENOSPC`.  We won't loop endlessly trying to write data to a full disk.  And we'll be able to handle other reasons that `write()` might reasonably fail to write out all of its data.